# Django REST Framework: set required field in serializer but not in model

Tags: django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a model like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
   dt_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author, null=True, blank=True)
   filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
   original_width = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   original_height = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

How can I set author field required only in serializer?

Comment: I solved in that way:

```python
class PhotoCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use extra_kwargs in class Meta:

```
    class Meta:
          model = Photo
          fields = '__all__'
          extra_kwargs = {'author': {'read_only': True, 'required': False}}
```